# Accessing state inside action shows empty state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

After reloading the page (using vuexPersistedState) I access my state inside an action like:

```
    updateOuterValue: ({
        commit
    }, data) => {
      console.log(state);
      ...
    }
```

The `localstorage` shows the preserved state, also it's delivered to the components as it should.
But inside the action the state is empty. How comes it shows empty state values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it. I can use `getters` to access the state inside an `action`:

```
    updateOuterValue: ({
        commit,
        getters
    }, data) => {
      ...
      console.log(getters.getForm); // WORKS
      ...
    }
```

Another way doing this is handling the `state` directly, like:

```
    updateOuterValue: ({
        commit,
        state       // <--- HERE
    }, data) => { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of your action method is the context and the second one is the payload :

```
 updateOuterValue: (context, data) => { 
   //here you could get access to the other options via context

     context.state.outerValue=data;

 }
```

or destruct the context as you did in your answer